# Multiple http request

Tags: http, testing, web-applications, scripting

To test my web-app for a peculiar test case, i need to fire about 20 http requests concurrently. I thought of writing a PERL script for this but then I wanted to check if there is a ready-made solution or script already available to do this.

Any help guys?

PS: Just curious if there a desktop application for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `ab` (apachebench): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and
>   dynamic resources (files, Servlets, Perl scripts, Java Objects, Data
>   Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more). It can be used to simulate a
>   heavy load on a server, network or object to test its strength or to
>   analyze overall performance under different load types. You can use it
>   to make a graphical analysis of performance or to test your
>   server/script/object behavior under heavy concurrent load.